# variable resolution with factory function

Tags: python, django

I got an interesting/frustrating Python problem I can not solve.
We have this code:

```
def eventtag_with_view_factory(view):
    print "==1", view

    class Cls(models.EventTag):

        # means this class does not make django change the database
        class Meta:
            proxy = True

        print "==2", view

        @permalink
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            print "==3", view
            return ("search_query_view", (),
                {'query': quote('#') + self.name, 'view': view})

    return Cls
```

It is a factory function that returns an EventTag with different
absolute urls.

If we call this once everything works fine, but when we call it twice
(it is called from a for loop) the 1. and 2. print statement give us the
new view, but the 3. one still uses the first value called with our
factory function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about django, but I can't reproduce this with a very simple script that I wrote to mimic yours...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, my only guess would be that you're seeing something like this: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/